# Как в babel command line задать несколько прессетов

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel

Как задать несколько пресетов?

```
--source-maps --out-file script.js --presets [es2015,stage-0] script.es6
```

как мне перечислить несколько пресетов? `--presets [es2015,stage-0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ: через запятую, без пробелов

```
--presets es2015,stage-0
```